# Error en rutas al controlador en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

mi problema es que tengo una vista que quiero conectar con un controlador pero al hacerlo me da el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «contador» (SQL: select * from "sistemas" where "sistemas"."id" = contador limit 1)

Y mi ruta es:

> Route::resource('sistema','controlSistema');

para cargar las funciones por defecto (index, create, store, update, show, etc) no me da ningun problema, pero al crear mis propias funciones tengo este problema, ¿cual podria ser la causa?

---

este es el controlador al cual hace referencia la view

`<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Sistema;

use Carbon\carbon;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

class controlSistema extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(){
        $sistemas=Sistema::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
        return view('Sistema.index',compact('sistemas'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //
        $now = Carbon::now();
        return view('Sistema.create')->with(compact('now'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        Sistema::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('sistema.index')->with('success','Registro creado satisfactoriamente');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $sistemas=Sistema::find($id);
        return  view('Sistema.show',compact('sistemas'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $sistemas=Sistema::find($id);
        return view('Sistema.edit',compact('sistemas'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[ 'nombre'=>'required', 'fecha'=>'required', 'tipo'=>'required']);

        Sistema::find($id)->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('sistema.index')->with('success','Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente');
    }

    public function contador(){
        return view('Sistema.count');
    }

}`

Comment: el problema es de sintaxis muestra la vista del controlador controlSistema

Comment: es que no retorna a una sola vista, dentro tengo redirecciones a distintas vistas pero usando funciones por defecto como public function index() o create(), y funcionan perfecto, excepto cuando uso funciones propias

Comment: debes estar colocandola mas hay dice que estas haciendo mal un query estas mandando una variable «contador» que no es un numero

Comment: la funcion es simple     

public function contador(){
        return view('Sistema.count');
    }

Comment: Ahí menciona un error con una consulta, la pudieras agregar¿?

Comment: el error me manda es a esta funcion que ejecuta la consulta

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $sistemas=Sistema::find($id);
        return  view('Sistema.show',compact('sistemas'));
    }

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene `id` cuando llega al método `find`?

Comment: ese viene dado de los registros que hay en la base de datos, por eso lo conecto al modelo que es quien los trae

Comment: Si pero ahi dice que la sintaxis de entrada no es válida, por eso me gustaría saber si nos puedes compartir que valor llega en la variable `id`, considerando que esta espera si no me equivoco el id de la tabla en cuestión

Comment: el valor viene de el campo id de la tabla, y hay lo uso para mostrar los datos en el index, segun lo que creo esta a la espera del id porque tiene el parametro en la funcion show($id), lo que no entiendo es porque me la sigue pidiendo para otra funcion

Comment: haber como le estas mandando el valor en la url del show para que te muestres ese problema has un dd($id)

Comment: solo me muestra esto "select * from "sistemas""
[]

Comment: lo esta tomando vacio

Comment: pero lo que quiero es que al colocar la direccion /sistema/count, me envie al formulario pero no me esta dejando, al hacerlo con funciones predefinidas como /sistema/index o /sistema/create me lleva a los formularios respectivos sin problema

Comment: te estamos diciendo muestra tu controlador completo haber cual puede ser lo que esta pasando

Comment: ya lo coloque, el controlador al cual enlazo la ruta

Answer (score 1):

Para poder utilizar una ruta priemero la debes definir en `routes/web.php`, si utilizas `Route::resource('sistema','controlSistema');` esto genera las siguientes rutas:

```
+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Method    | URI                       | Name              | Action                                          | Middleware   |
+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| GET|HEAD  | sistema                   | sistema.index     | App\Http\Controllers\controlSistema@index       | web          |
| POST      | sistema                   | sistema.store     | App\Http\Controllers\controlSistema@store       | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | sistema/create            | sistema.create    | App\Http\Controllers\controlSistema@create      | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | sistema/{sistema}         | sistema.show      | App\Http\Controllers\controlSistema@show        | web          |
| PUT|PATCH | sistema/{sistema}         | sistema.update    | App\Http\Controllers\controlSistema@update      | web          |
| DELETE    | sistema/{sistema}         | sistema.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\controlSistema@destroy     | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | sistema/{sistema}/edit    | sistema.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\controlSistema@edit        | web          |
+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Puedes añadir ademas las rutas que necesites teniendo cuidado para que no den conflictos entre ellas que es lo que te esta sucediendo. Cuando llamas a la ruta `sistema/contador` te esta cargando la ruta definida para `sistema.show`.

Por ejemplo esto podría crear un conflicto o mejor dicho no interpretar las rutas `sistema/contador` y `sistema/{sistema} sistema.show` como esperamos:

```
Route::resource('sistema','controlSistema');
Route:get('sistema/contador', 'controlSistema@contador');
```

Las rutas mencionadas podrian quedar así:

```
+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Method    | URI                       | Name              | Action                                          | Middleware   |
+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| GET|HEAD  | sistema/{sistema}         | sistema.show      | App\Http\Controllers\controlSistema@show        | web          |
| GET       | sistema/contador          |                   | App\Http\Controllers\controlSistema@contador    | web          |
+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Si te fijas las rutas pueden ser ambiguas por que Laravel no sabrá si lo que se envia es un valor dinámico o forma parte de la ruta por lo que cargara la primera que coincida (la primera que este definida), lo mas fácil es tener en cuenta el orden de definición de las rutas, definiendo primero la ruta `sistema/contador` y por último el resource.

```
Route:get('sistema/contador', 'controlSistema@contador');
Route::resource('sistema','controlSistema');
```

No obstante lo recomendable es crear restricciones, por ejemplo para que la ruta `sistema.show` solo sea tenida en cuenta cuando se en via un número:

```
// añadimos las rutas del resource menos show
Route::resource('sistema','controlSistema')->except(['show']);
// creamos la ruta show y restrungimos con el where
Route:get('sistema/{sistema}', 'controlSistema@show')->name('sistema.show')->where('sistema', '[0-9]+');
//cremos nuestra ruta personalizada
Route:get('sistema/contador', 'controlSistema@contador');
```

Ducumentación Laravel:

- [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing)
- [Resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers)